# How did a question get asked without tags?

Tags: support, tags

The SE software requires you to specify at least one tag when posting, and [untagged](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) is a special tag that you're not supposed to be able to add directly.

How did [this question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/15949/1993) have, as its sole tag, [untagged](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) in its first revision?  It was not migrated from another site, which is how that usually happens.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: In other news, [tag:untagged] has accumulated a bunch of questions, presumably in large part because of single-use tags evaporating.  (Re)taggings there are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the blacklist I put in place to prevent folks from using that tag didn't get used for a really long time and the system deleted it.

I've restored it, along with some descriptive text:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to lock the tag so it can not be deleted? Maby put on a locked question?